# MassTransit RabbitMQ Node distribution

Tags: rabbitmq, esb, masstransit

I'm investigating using MassTransit with RabbitMQ in our application as an ESB. The main benefit I'm looking for is adding durable asynchronous messaging processing to the incoming data stream.

Our application profile has two parts:

Incoming data stream

- One way messaging
- Processed asynchronously
- 10k+ messages per minute

Website activity

- Two way
- Ideally use c# async await language features but requires data in both directions
- < 100 per minute

The web app messaging isn't a necessity but would be nice to follow the same mechanism to full abstract away data access through the ESB.

**Questions:**

From what I've read; an ESB node should not know or care about any other node on the bus, it should just do it's own work and send messages onto the bus, waiting for replies if/when required. To me that means each web / app server would have it's own local clustered queue.
Is this assumption correct?

If that is correct; how would I programmatically add machines to the cluster? Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of?

If this is not correct; how would I manage the queue cluster? Creating a dedicated cluster has it's own problems such as DNS entries, load-balancing for redundancy / offline nodes, etc

I'm down with the functionality ESBs can add along with MassTransit's implementation however I am a little clouded with the logistics of the best practices of where / how to set it up in a durable configuration.

Thanks for any feedback & advice

**Update**
We are utilising EC2 for machine infrastructure, in particular we use availability zones to minimise any data center outages. With this configuration we have 3 zones, each zone has a web server, app server and db server (Couchbase). We also utilise EC2's load balancers to share load between the zones.

@Travis: Do you have any experience / advice of using MT / RMQ within Amazon's EC2?

Comment: I don't have any experience with EC2 and RabbitMQ. We have a private data center for our software. Clustered RabbitMQ instances sound like what you need though. Then your application only am cares about the central location of your RabbitMQ cluster. App parts won't care about where they live.

Comment: Yeah, that is the same point I've arrived at too. I'll be looking at a mirrored clustered configuration to use HA message durability. I need to figure out if it's worth trying a grid approach where RabbitMQ will be installed on each machine that will host a process that interacts with the cluster, or if a hub and spoke approach with dedicated messaging servers behind a load balancer (as your example) would be best. Thanks for your input @Travis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So at a scale that's significantly larger than yours, we have a RabbitMQ cluster that sites behind a load balance (an F5). The all processes using MT reference the load balanced address. The only thing each process needs is it's own queue to receive from.

Clustering in RabbitMQ (3.0+) is all handled in the RabbitMQ configuration. The processes/code knows nothing about the clustering.

I'm not sure what you mean by "node" in this question, so it's hard to make sure I'm answering the right question. But as soon as you add a process to the same vhost (default or otherwise) in RabbitMQ, MT will connect all the pieces it needs (exchanges, queues, and bindings).

Comment: I took too long on my edit and had to make another comment.

I'll updated my question with a few more details to try and give you a clearer picture of what my environment is.

Comment: Hey Mike, did you end up going with the "local cluster nodes" example that Adam suggested, or the cluster behind a load-balanced setup that Travis uses?  Travis, do you mind weighing in on Adam's suggestion, and why you went with the load balanced cluster instead?  I'm assuming to reduce the cluster synchronization traffic to all the nodes giving better scale, right?

Comment: Mike's setup does work. But if a machine is lost connection to the cluster it's useless anyways - at least to us. Besides we have websites that we want lightweight as possible instead of having RMQ on those machines.

Answer (score 1):

We run a different approach to Travis.
Every machine that has a service that consumes/processes or publishes messages are also nodes in the RabbitMq cluster.
Every machine then only has to address RabbitMq via localhost

Each service is on more than one machine
To achieve this we are using Competing consumers (i.e. multiple machines will be reading from the same clustered queue (but via localhost))
So your architecture has to allow for parallel processing of messages.

If a machine goes down, there is at least another one that has the dead machines services.

If lots of machines go down, there are other machines with all the messages stored and you can deploy the services to them.

Comment: Hi Adam - thanks for your reply. I've come up with a very similar pattern as I like allowing my services to talk to the service bus via local host.

Comment: I know this is a fairly old question, but having spent a few months trying to use this approach, I found that cluster partitions were very hard to avoid with so many nodes running on production machines. Do you see that too, or do you just have an exceptionally reliable network between machines?

Comment: we only ever had 4 nodes. Wasnt a problem for us, they are all in the same datacenter? I.e. not over VPN's or anything.

Comment: We had 2 disk nodes on dedicated machines and 8 ram nodes for the various servers. All in the same datacenter. I wasn't ever able to find a good reason why some nodes would lose visibility of others, and it didn't happen very often. But when it did happen the recovery was often way harder than I expected, and all the time my live application(s) had no message bus. We've fallen back to using a small number of core disk nodes and I'm looking at setting up a load balancer now, which is how I came across this question again